# automatic login after signup

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I'm trying to, after create an account, login the user automatcally.
Need to redirect them to `/auth/local/` send the user and password that he just created.

This is my `middleware/signup.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
return function(req, res, next) {
const body = req.body;

// Get the user service and `create` a new user
app.service('users').create({
  email: body.email,
  password: body.password
})
// Then redirect to the login page
.then(user => app.post('/auth/local', function(req, res){
   req.body(user);
}))
// On errors, just call our error middleware
.catch(next);
 };
};
```

This dont give any errors...Just a eternal loading after creating an User.
Help

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is an eternal loading because you are not sending a response or calling `next`. Please read [about express middlewares here](http://expressjs.com/es/guide/using-middleware.html).

Besides that, why do you want to make a POST request to your own API from itself? I don't have enough context here about what `app` is but your code looks more like a route definition, than like a request.
Here you should have some way to call a function that authenticates the user.
For example if using passport:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
return function(req, res, next) {
const body = req.body;

// Get the user service and `create` a new user
app.service('users').create({
  email: body.email,
  password: body.password
})
// Then redirect to the login page
.then(user => passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, next))
// On errors, just call our error middleware
.catch(next);
 };
};
```